# Blur depth in swift 5

Tags: swift

How to change blur depth in swift? I found a code with which i blurred my UIView, but it blurs to hard, how i can decrease blur depth (radius)? Here is code example

```
    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
        
        let blurEffect = UIBlurEffect(style: .light)
        let blurView = UIVisualEffectView(effect: blurEffect)
        blurView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        view.insertSubview(blurView, at: 0)
        
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
          blurView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor),
          blurView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor),
          blurView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.heightAnchor),
          blurView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.widthAnchor)
        ])
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do it using this animation trick

```
var animator = UIViewPropertyAnimator(duration: 1, curve: .linear)     
var effect = UIBlurEffect?
private func blurIt() {
    animator.stopAnimation(true)
    effect = nil

    animator.addAnimations { [weak self] in
        self?.effect = UIBlurEffect(style: .light)
    }
    animator.fractionComplete = 0.1   //This is your blur intensity in range 0 - 1
}
```

or you can try changing the alpha of the blurView

```
blurView.alpha = 0.1
```

Obviously the final result is not the same

Comment: yep, this "blurView.alpha = 0.1" worked, thanx a lot

Comment: @Chrissy Just beware that Apple says to "avoid alpha values that are less than 1". https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uivisualeffectview#1681444